# When would garbage collection occur in this Java code?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In my sample code, which of my `Test` objects will be eligible for garbage collection at the end of execution?

```
interface Animal1
{
    void makeNoise();
}


class Horse implements Animal1
{
    Long weight = 1200L;

    @Override
    public void  makeNoise()
    {
        System.out.println("Whinny");
    }
}

public class Test extends Horse
{
    public void makeNoise()
    {
        System.out.println("wginny");
    }

    public static void main(String str[])
    {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        Test t2 = new Test();
        Test t3 = new Test();
        t3 = t1;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = null;
        t3 = t1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'd likely drive home the concept more if you tried printing the values yourself to see what you get.

Comment: I suppose the question is how many are eligible at the end of main. The answer: all of them since the program is exiting...

Answer (score 1):

```
    Test t1=new Test();
    Test t2=new Test();
    Test t3=new Test();
    t3=t1; 
    t1=t2;
    t2=null;
    t3=t1;
```

The answer would be t3 and t1. 
t2 still has a reference that is stored into t1, and then stored into t3. the original objects created for t1 and t3 are eligible for garbage collection as they no longer have strong references anymore since different values were saved to them. A good mental exercise, but this is probably homework that you just copy pasted anyways.

The longs are all eligible for garbage collection once strong references to their enclosing object disappear.

Alternatively, all of the objects are eligible for garbage collection if your application exits.

Comment: Don't forget the `Long`s.

Comment: the longs don't matter, they are inside of the Test derived type, I guess you could say they are all eligible for garbage collection, but the critical part of this question is just dealing with setting references.

Comment: That is still an object that will be collected... And your reasoning is wrong: the original t1 is still reachable through t3 at the end.

Comment: They do matter. One will get instantiated with each instance of Test. So when any reference to a test object is removed they become island instanced, and as such are eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: yeah. I think we're being a little overly pedantic here, it's pretty clear what the actual problem is, and it doesn't have to do with nested object references. my answer solves the problem adequately. If we wanted to be even more pedantic we could pick at even more insignificant parts such as the fact that he forgot a curly brace :P

Comment: It *is* pretty clear. They asked how many objects, and the Longs are objects and they are eligible once the reference to their holding class is gone. This question style is popular in the official Java programmer certification. They would crucify you for missing the Longs.

Comment: Also, @assylias you are wrong, both t1 and t3 references go away. the value of t1 is saved to t3, and then the value of t2 is saved to t1, and then the value of t1(which is t2) is saved to t3. so i'd appreciate if you took your downvote away, thanks.

Comment: @Rudi ok, point taken. I made assumptions based on what I knew about enclosed object references.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but I count 6.

```
1: Test t1 original value
2: Test t2 original value
3: Test t3 original value
4: Long t1.weight (autoboxed. not flyweighted because of the high value)
5: Long t2.weight (autoboxed. not flyweighted because of the high value)
6: Long t3.weight (autoboxed. not flyweighted because of the high value)
```

Note that any methods called would only allocate 1 flyweighted string. Strings are immutable & Java would share these references.

Comment: makeNoise() is never called so the String is never created.

Comment: is flyweighted the right term to use here? isn't it just the string constant pool that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Yes, it's the right term. The string constant pool is a mechanism to flyweight strings. The strings would be allocated from the string constant pool, as you point out. The longs are stored differently but the purpose is the same.